# Who can tell me how to init a ex object with a string?

Tags: c++, string, math, ginac

Does anyone use the GINAC? Can you tell me how to init an `ex` object with a string, or convert a string to `ex`?

Comment: Doesn't the constructor documented here do it: http://www.ginac.de/reference/classGiNaC_1_1ex.html#ace68037326c1a2b8c93a56716599ec7a

Comment: I have tried this method,but it can't work!And what is the meaning of the second parameter ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string that contains the correct expression syntax, you can use the constructor documented [here](http://www.ginac.de/reference/classGiNaC_1_1ex.html#ace68037326c1a2b8c93a56716599ec7a) to turn it into an `ex` object.

You need to supply a second argument, which must be a list (in the sense of a `lst` object) of symbols. This list must contain the user-defined symbols you use in the expression. If you don't use any user-defined symbols, use an empty list.

Example with no user-defined symbols:

```
  using namespace std;
  using namespace GiNaC;

  ex myex("2+3",lst());      // Output will be '5'

  cout myex << endl;
```

Example using two user-defined symbols:

```
  using namespace std;
  using namespace GiNaC;

  symbol x("x");
  symbol y("y");
  ex myex("x^3+y",lst(x,y));

  cout << myex + y << endl;     // Output will be '2*y+x^3'
```

In the last example, you can see that the character `'y'` in the input string `"x^3+y"` was indeed interpreted as the symbol `y`: `myex + y` is simplified to `"2*y+x^3"`.

Comment: Sorry,I think you have not understood what I mean.I show an example.

Comment: string s("Hello");
ex e;
How to pass the value of string s to ex e?

Comment: e can implement many mathematical operations,such as add(), expand(), factor and so on.

Comment: I have solved the problem.Just like what you said.I can use e(s,lst()) to implement.

Comment: Just like this,I want to read a string and show the result on the mai screen.
- (NSString *)combine:(NSString *)input{
    symbol x("x");
    symbol y("y");
    string str("");
    ex b;
    str = [input  cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ex ec(str,lst(x,y));
    cout<<"ec is"<<ec<<endl;
    ex polys = add(ec,0);
    ostringstream osstr;
    osstr<<polys;    
    NSString *outstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:osstr.str().c_str()];
    return outstr;
}

Comment: on the main screen,not the mai screen